# Cleanly interrupt HttpListener's BeginGetContext method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, httplistener

I am using a [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34xswsd2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and using [BeginGetContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.begingetcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get my context object. I want to cleanly shut down my HttpListener but if I attempt to do a [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.close%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the listener I get a exception and it causes my program to exit.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace Sandbox_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
                return;
            }

            // Create a listener.
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://vwdev.vw.local:8081/BitsTest/");
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

            listener.BeginGetContext(Context, listener);
            Console.ReadLine();

            listener.Close(); //Exception on this line, but not shown in Visual Studio
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped Listening..."); //This line is never reached.
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void Context(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

            context.Response.Close();
            listener.BeginGetContext(Context, listener);
        }
    }
}
```

The program throws a exception on the `listener.Close()` however the error never gets shown in Visual Studio, the only note I get is the following in the Debug output screen:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
>   The program '[2568] Sandbox Console.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I was able to get the real execption from windows Event Viewer

```
Application: Sandbox Console.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ObjectDisposedException
Stack:
   at System.Net.HttpListener.EndGetContext(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Sandbox_Console.Program.Context(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

What do I need to do so I can close my HttpListener cleanly?

Comment: So your async `static void Context` never gets called? .. something has gone awry.. `ObjectDisposedException`'s are thrown when you attempt to dispose of an object that is already disposed. Something tells me the initialization of your listener is broken.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead AH AH! Context gets called one last time when you call Close. Writing up a solution.

Comment: Why are you calling `BeginGetContext()` after calling `.Close()`?

Comment: @TomLint because it is waiting for the next call to start.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I read your Context function incorrectly, and thought you'd just closed the listener instead of the response.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Context gets called one last time when you call Close, you must handle the object disposed exception that could get thrown

```
static void Context(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;

   try
   {
        //If we are not listening this line throws a ObjectDisposedException.
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

        context.Response.Close();
        listener.BeginGetContext(Context, listener);
   }
   catch (ObjectDisposedException)
   {
       //Intentionally not doing anything with the exception.
   }
}
```

Comment: This is broken because it might cause legitimate contexts to get lost.

Comment: The only way to shut down a listener that I know is to catch and handle the exception... disgusting API problem. Just like with sockets.

Comment: @usr I don't know why I did not think of that the first time around, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this line

```
if (!listener.IsListening) { return; }
HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(ctx);
```

Comment: Actually, if you look at the revision history of my answer that is is exactly what my code used to do and usr pointed out that doing that can cause legitimate contexts to get lost and I updated my answer to the current way.